# Angular Loading Indicator Custom element Directive

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-directive

I have written custom angular element directive, which shows/hides loading indicator based on condition evaluated on service call. The directive is applied as element to element. The directive works fine, but the problem the content is of the applied element not hidding.

Here is my **directive:**

```
export interface ILoadingIndicatorAttr extends ng.IAttributes {
  efpLoadingIndicator: string;
}
 export interface ILoadingIndicatorscope extends ng.IScope {
   loading: boolean;
 }



export class LoadingIndicator implements ng.IDirective {
   public restrict: string = 'A';
   public replace: boolean = true;
   static $inject = ["$compile", "$templateRequest", "$timeout"];

constructor(public _compile: ng.ICompileService, private templateService: ng.ITemplateRequestService, private timeout: ng.ITimeoutService) {

};

link = (scope: ILoadingIndicatorscope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ILoadingIndicatorAttr, ngModel: ng.INgModelController): void => {
    var tempThis = this;
    var templateUrl: string = 'app/modules/common/directives/loadingIndicator/loadingIndicator.tmpl.html';
    attrs.$observe('efpLoadingIndicator', () => {
        if (attrs.efpLoadingIndicator == "true") {
            this.timeout(() => {
                if (attrs.efpLoadingIndicator == "true") {
                    scope.loading = true;
                    tempThis.resolveTemplate(templateUrl).then((html: ng.IAugmentedJQuery) => {
                        tempThis._compile(html)(scope).appendTo(element);                            
                    });
                }
                else {                      
                    scope.loading = false;
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
        else {
            scope.loading = false;
        }
    });
}

resolveTemplate = (templateUrl: string): ng.IPromise<ng.IAugmentedJQuery> => {
    return this.templateService(templateUrl).then((html: string) => {
        return angular.element(html);
    });
   }
}
```

Here is how it is applied:

```
 <div efp-loading-indicator ={{vm.isLoading}}>

  <select> </select>

 </div
```

I want to hide the content of div when loading indicator is present, show when loading indicator is off. I know i can use ng-show on child elements but don't want to do that since I want to reuse this directive.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `this` is not what you expect in the link function. At that point,`this` will be referring to the `window` object (and thus `tempThis` too).

If you need to use the `link` function, you have to rebind it to `this` in the constructor, where `this` is referring to the class:

```
export interface ILoadingIndicatorAttr extends ng.IAttributes {
   efpLoadingIndicator: string;
}

export interface ILoadingIndicatorscope extends ng.IScope {
   loading: boolean;
}

export class LoadingIndicator implements ng.IDirective {
   public restrict: string = 'A';
   public replace: boolean = true;
   link:(scope: ILoadingIndicatorscope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ILoadingIndicatorAttr, ngModel: ng.INgModelController)=> void

   static $inject = ["$compile", "$templateRequest", "$timeout"];

constructor(public _compile: ng.ICompileService, private templateService: ng.ITemplateRequestService, private timeout: ng.ITimeoutService) {
    this.link = this.myLink.bind(this);
};

myLink(scope: ILoadingIndicatorscope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ILoadingIndicatorAttr, ngModel: ng.INgModelController): void => {
    var tempThis = this;
    var templateUrl: string = 'app/modules/common/directives/loadingIndicator/loadingIndicator.tmpl.html';
    attrs.$observe('efpLoadingIndicator', () => {
        if (attrs.efpLoadingIndicator == "true") {
            this.timeout(() => {
                if (attrs.efpLoadingIndicator == "true") {
                    scope.loading = true;
                    tempThis.resolveTemplate(templateUrl).then((html: ng.IAugmentedJQuery) => {
                        tempThis._compile(html)(scope).appendTo(element);                            
                    });
                }
                else {                      
                    scope.loading = false;
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
        else {
            scope.loading = false;
        }
    });
}

resolveTemplate = (templateUrl: string): ng.IPromise<ng.IAugmentedJQuery> =>{
    return this.templateService(templateUrl).then((html: string) => {
        return angular.element(html);
    });
   }
}
```